# Images not showing up in tkinter GUI window

Tags: python, image, tkinter

Basically I'm having trouble opening images (.jpg) in a tkinter GUI window.

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lt78_05hHSk

But I just get a blank window.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Desktop\123k.jpg")
# photo = PhotoImage(file="123k.jpg")
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The file path is correct and `.jpg` files are compatible with `tkinter`. What could be going on?

I get this error

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\xxx\ytrewq.py", line 5, 
in <module> photo = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Desktop\123k.jpg") 
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 3545,
in init Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 3501, 
in init self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options) 
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file 
"C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Desktop\123k.jpg"
```

Comment: Please write down the specific error you received, and also save your image file as `.png`. I've run your code and I get the error `TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "/Users/Siddarth/Desktop/ClMsNHW.jpg` if I try a jpg and I am sucessful if I try a `.png`

Comment: The error is telling you what's wrong: tkinter doesn't support jpg.

Comment: Please don't put code and tracebacks in comments. [edit] your question add it there.

Comment: Awesome. Png files work. Thanks.

Comment: @Emilio, Glad to hear it, if you wish to use  a `.jpg`, then I recommend this article here (https://pythonbasics.org/tkinter-image/). Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because only PhotoImage function can't recognize the .jpg formate image. For this, you could use png formate or you could use

> Image.open(path_of_the_file) and then

> ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_object)

for this Image and ImageTk you have to import this from PIL module

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

The hole solution code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

# photo = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Desktop\123k.jpg")
# photo = PhotoImage(file="123k.jpg")
img = Image.open(file=r"C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Desktop\123k.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```